# "Login failed for user" when using admin user in SSMS

Tags: ssms, azure-sql-database, azure

I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL database via SSMS. The connection string supplied by Azure is:

> Server=tcp:SERVER_NAME.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

So, first of all I'm not sure if I should include ALL of

```
tcp:SERVER_NAME.database.windows.net,1433
```

in the server name when connecting via SSMS.   Also, the username is an email address.  Let's say it's:

```
foo@bar.com
```

So, this is what I tried:

```
ServerName: SERVER_NAME.database.windows.net
Login:      foo@bar.com@SERVER_NAME.database.windows.net
Password:   [password]
```

At first when I tried, I was told that the IP was not allowed.  So I added the IP to the server firewall settings.  But now, I get this:

> Login failed for user foo@bar.com

I am using the same UserID and Password that I use to log into the Azure portal.  And it's the UserID that is specified in the Access Control window.

I am working from home, but I have also tried while on my company's VPN.  Neither work.

Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Voting to close since the issue was setup related and user didn't have actual permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the problem is in the username. When you connect to an Azure SQL Database instance, foo@bar implies that you're connecting as the login "foo" to the instance "bar.database.windows.net".

The credentials you use when logging into the Azure management portal won't work when you're using SSMS.

Verify that you've set up a *SQL Database* login, and use that login. The admin account is set up in the Azure portal - you can verify the login name by clicking "Properties" on the server instance.

Regular logins/users are set up as 1) logins on the database server, or 2) as contained users in each database (if you have enabled containment), or 3) in Active Directory (if you've configured one).

Comment: ok, thanks!  I was under the impression that adding @server after the email would solve the problem.  That's why I was trying `foo@bar.com@SERVER_NAME.database.windows.net`.  And also, I can not see any way, via the Azure portal, to add a Database user.  Any hints would be appreciated!!

Comment: If memory serves (not at my computer right now), you can reset the admin password from the portal. Look for the support/troubleshooting tab. Regular users can then be set up in T-SQL using that login.

Comment: "Regular users can then be set up in T-SQL using that login"  Yes, but you have to actually be logged in to do this, and I can't even log in!!

Comment: In the Azure portal, click the Azure SQL Database instance, go to the "Overview" tab. On the top bar, the fourth button from the left is called "Reset password". See if that works for you. The login name of the admin is displayed just below, under "Server admin".

Comment: ok, I will give that a shot.  But, I just used this same UserID and Password to log into the Azure portal.  So I'm assuming I have it right.  Or, are the creds for logging into the Portal and logging into the Sql Server not the same?

Comment: I changed the admin password and tried that in SSMS. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

Bah.  This server and elastic pool was created by my boss.  I got permission from him to wipe it out and start over. When I created it myself, I was able to log in from SSMS no problem.